# how to punctuate a sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons

How should this sentence be punctuated? I've run it past all the online grammar checkers I could find and they seem to think all 4 are acceptable.

1. In my house when the heat is off the pipes freeze.
2. In my house: when the heat is off the pipes freeze.
3. In my house: when the heat is off, the pipes freeze.
4. In my house, when the heat is off, the pipes freeze.
5. In my house, when the heat is off the pipes freeze.

I'm favoring item 5 with the reasoning that "In my house" is an introductory element and "when the heat is off" is not an independent clause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is clearly number 4.

"When the heat is off" is a subordinate clause that precedes both the complete subject "the pipes" and the verb "freeze."  As such, it must be offset by commas.

Imagine the sentence without the prepositional phrase "in my house":

> *When the heat is off my pipes freeze.*
>
> or
>
> *When the heat is off, my pipes freeze.*

Since you were able to identify the introductory phrase "in my house," do you see how "when the heat is off" introduces and modifies in a very similar way?  The only difference is that "when the heat is off" is a subordinate clause, whereas "in my house" is a prepositional phrase.  Aside from that, though, they perform the same modifying function in anticipation of the main clause.

Reference: [Dependent/Subordinate Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)

***Why are the rest wrong?***

> 1. In my house when the heat is off the pipes freeze.

This is incorrect because it contains no punctuation between the subordinate clause "when the heat is off" and the main clause "the pipes freeze."

> 2. In my house: when the heat is off the pipes freeze.
> 3. In my house: when the heat is off, the pipes freeze.

These are wrong because they improperly use a colon after "house."  "In my house" is not an independent clause nor does it qualify in any other way for having a colon follow it.

> In my house, when the heat is off the pipes freeze.

This sentence is wrong for the same reason as number 1, because it contains no punctuation between the subordinate clause "when the heat is off" and the main clause "the pipes freeze."

Comment: I'm curious why you got downvoted. I was hoping they'd come forward with some alternate grammatical theory that you two could argue over. But, that doesn't seem to be happening. So, I'll give you a +1 in addition to the check to offset the drive-by downvoter's bad karma. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree. The sentence *When the heat is off the pipes freeze* certainly doesn't need any commas, and I don't see any absolute reason why you should need to add *two* commas just because you've added *one* subordinate clause (regardless of whether we consider that clause subordinate to *When the heat is off* or to *the pipes freeze*. Personally I'm quite happy with OP's #1 (no commas at all), but my second choice would be #5 (just set off the "secondary" subordinate clause - but since it's been "moved" to the start of the sentence, there's no initial comma *before* it).

Comment: There he is! Fight! Fight! Fight!

Comment: @PaulH : I provided a reference link.  Here is another.  Scroll down to the part where it says "subordinate clause+,+ main clause." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)

Comment: References shmeferences. I demand grammatical correctness by combat. BTW: should there be a comma between "references" and "shmeferences"? A semicolon? English is tough, man.

Comment: @PaulH : Here is another.  It also explains how a comma is absolutely required between the subordiante clause "when the heat is off" and the main clause "my pipes freeze." Scroll down to the part where it reads, "Comma Use with Adverbial Clauses."   (http://www.towson.edu/ows/AdvAdjNomClause.htm)

Comment: @PaulH : Lol.  No, there's no convention for putting a comma between *something* and its subsequent *schmomething.*

Comment: @PaulH : I might have said that it didn't need any commas if the only thing introducing the main clause had been the prepositional phrase "in my house."  It's been deemed that, when a prepositional phrase that introduces a sentence that has three words or less (http://www.towson.edu/ows/AdvAdjNomClause.htm - see rule 5), we needn't have a comma between it and the main clause.  However, since there is an interceding subordinate clause, there does need to be a comma that separates it from the subordinate clause.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, bro.  Check out deadrat's answer.

Answer (score 5):

This question, like all matters of punctuation, is a matter of style, and as such, you should be guided by your manual of style.  There are two basic philosophies, close punctuation and open.  Roughly speaking, the former advocates placing marks whenever there is an occasion to emphasize the syntax; the latter requires the marks only when unavoidable ambiguity arise in their absence.  *The New Yorker* is famous for using a close style.  Bear in mind that manuals of either style will acknowledge that exceptions arise and that an author's judgment is indispensable.

I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which would advise that short introductory phrases like "in my house" may forgo the following comma, but that introductory adverbial clauses may not.  The colon is used for special circumstances -- preceding a list introduced with the word *following* or before explanatory or conclusory text.  That would leave you with

> In my house when the heat is off, the pipes freeze.

*The New Yorker* would likely opt for

> In my house, when the heat is off, the pipes freeze.

An open punctuator might recommend

> In my house when the heat is off the pipes freeze.

Reasoning that no one would attempt a parse that says "off the pipes."

There's no right or wrong answer, certainly not a grammatical one.  This isn't a matter of grammar.  If you have had a style manual thrust upon you, your editor (or professor) will likely enforce it.  If you're lucky enough to be able to adopt a manual you choose, your own judgment can be the arbiter.

Comment: +1 because now I know that when I invent a time machine, I can go back to the 5th grade and tell my English teacher that I subscribe to the "New Yorker" style of punctuation.